# Pull latest changes for all git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

We're using git submodules to manage a couple of large projects that have dependencies on many other libraries we've developed. Each library is a separate repo brought into the dependent project as a submodule. During development, we often want to just go grab the latest version of every dependent submodule.

How do I pull the latest changes for all git submodules?

Comment: [git-deep](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/git-deep) should help with this.

Comment: @Brad do you want to update your copies of submodules to the commit revs named in the master project; or do you want to pull the latest HEAD commit from every submodule? Most of the answers here address the former; many people want the latter.

Comment: You can find this answer with Git flow with submodules helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/70910397/9566462

Answer (score 3631, accepted):

If it's **the first time** you check-out a repo you need to use `--init` first:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

For **git 1.8.2** or above, the option `--remote` was added to support updating to latest tips of remote branches:

```
git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

This has the added benefit of respecting any "non default" branches specified in the `.gitmodules` or `.git/config` files (if you happen to have any, default is origin/master, in which case some of the other answers here would work as well).

For **git 1.7.3** or above you can use (but the below gotchas around what update does still apply):

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

or:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

if you want to pull your submodules to latest commits instead of the current commit the repo points to.

See [git-submodule(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) for details

Comment: Great that's what I needed.  Note though that when using msys-git in a Window's command prompt you need something later than v1.5.6.  I had to upgrade to 1.6.3 to get it to work.  Thanks again.

Comment: As it says, you need to modify the executed command to suit your needs. I've set it up to fetch whatever the current branch is tracking and rebase it onto the current branch, which is a pretty handy thing to have set up :)

Comment: Now here's a question for you: Can you make that so it is recursive? i.e. `git submodule foreach` also gets run in each submodule

EDIT: nvm, just use `--recurse-submodules`

Comment: Probably you should use `git submodule update --recursive` nowadays.

Comment: Performance improvement: `git submodule foreach "(git checkout master; git pull)&"`

Comment: update will update each submodule to the specified revision, not update it to the latest for that repository.

Comment: is there a way to do something like: `git submodule foreach "(git checkout <current branch>; git pull)&"`

Comment: You can add branch information with `git submodule add -b <branch>` as per http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule when adding them, or later manually by adding the line `branch = <branch>` to the section of the module in `.gitmodules`. When branch of every module is specified `git submodule foreach git pull` should work without `... origin master`.

Comment: Hi @xp-vit, I've rolled back your [last revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1032653/2), please don't change other people's non-wiki answers like that, either comment on the post (when you have enough reputation), or add another answer, where appropriate.

Comment: Just to add, blindly sticking `origin master` at the end of this command might have unexpected results if some of your submodules are tracking a different branch or location name of that particular submodule. Obvious to some, but probably not to everyone.

Comment: This command is not working for me, submodule code is not pulled.

Comment: Just to clarify for everyone. `git submodule update --recursive` looks to see which revision the parent repository has stored for each submodule, then checks out that revision in each submodule. It does **NOT** pull the latest commits for each submodule. `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` or `git pull origin master --recurse-submodules` is what you want if you intend to update each submodule to the latest from their origin repositories. Only then will you get pending changes in the parent repo with updated revision hashes for submodules. Check those in and you're good.

Comment: It seems only the first and last examples here *actually checkout the tip* of all submodules, which is what the OP was looking for, or am I mistaken?  So I'm going to come in here and add some warnings tomorrow if no response made to this comment by then (and remove this comment)...

Comment: Is it safe to run `git submodule update --init --recursive` if only *some* submodules have not been initiated yet?

Comment: I tried this answer on git 2.11.0 and it resulted in detached HEADs in submodules that were way behind previously checked branches. It works as @Chev describes it in his comment above and therefore *does not* answer the OPs question.

Comment: How do I checkout an specific branch on all submodules which will not be overridden by a submodule update

Comment: `--init` answer part should be moved to the top because that's all people want to know.

Comment: git submodule update --recursive --remote doesn't seem to work in my case.  I have a submodule within a submodule, and only the first tier is pulled.

Comment: It needs to be said that the note in the answer about checking out a repo for the first time applies to both 1.7.3+ AND 1.8.2+.  The format of the answer made this unclear.

Comment: @cowlinator: The answer has been edited by multiple people over the last 10 years since I wrote the original response. Too many cooks, perhaps :)

I moved the init bit to the top. Also removing the 1.6 info since the last 1.6 release was 9 years ago.

Comment: With the proposed answer, I get the `fatal: Needed a single revision` `Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path`.

Comment: @Friedrich that likely means that the repo's primary branch isn't `master`.  The default for Github is `main` now.  It kinda breaks this flow.

Comment: @Chev actually adding the `--remote` flag is enough to pull the latest commits

Comment: @MarcoPereira good to know. Not sure if that was true in 2015.

Comment: To see the progress of how much has been downloaded, pass the `--progress` flag i.e.`git submodule update --init --recursive --progress`. It is helpful in case you are downloading large repos.

Comment: `git submodule update --recursive --remote --init` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 719):

```
git pull --recurse-submodules --jobs=10
```

> **a feature git first learned in 1.8.5.**

Until the [bug](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_bugs) is fixed, for the first time you do need to run

> git submodule update --init --recursive

Comment: upvoted, i use this:  
alias update_submodules='git pull --recurse-submodules && git submodule update'

Comment: This works if the submodules have already been pulled at least once but for submodules that have never been checked out, see gahooa's answer below.

Comment: This will pull up to the version the top repo specifies; it does NOT pull HEAD. For example if TopRepo specifies a version 2 behind HEAD for SubRepo, this will pull SubRepo with that version that's 2 behind. Other answers here pull HEAD in SubRepo.

Comment: Note that neither `git pull --recurse-submodules` nor `git submodule update --recursive` does **not** initialize newly added submodules. To initialize them you need run `git submodule update --recursive --init`. Quote from [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule): *If the submodule is not yet initialized, and you just want to use the setting as stored in .gitmodules, you can automatically initialize the submodule with the --init option.*

Comment: maybe add a hint to `git submodule update --recursive --remote` which also updates the submodules to the remote latest revision instead of the stored SHA-1.

Comment: This doesn't actually update submod's to tip, I will come here and add a warning about that tomorrow (and delete this comment) if no response to this comment by then. cheers!

Comment: This is not working. I have a submodule and now nothing works.

Comment: Can we configure `--recurse-submodules` to be the default? I see `fetch.recurseSubmodules`, but not `pull.recurseSubmodules`...

Comment: This didn't work. I ran `git pull --recurse-submodules --jobs=10` and saw `Fetching submodule useful_scripts/ripgrep_replace`, but it didn't actually run a `git pull` inside that subrepo, rather, it only ran a `git fetch` inside that repo it looks like! How do I make it complete the process by merging that fetched data into my current `main` branch, like a `git pull` would do?

Comment: Finally! I found what I'm looking for! This works perfectly to update all submodules, recursively, to their latest from their upstreams: `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin main`, or if your main branches are called `master` instead: `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master`. See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032863/4561887).

Comment: Even better: just use `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull`, so that it will pull whatever upstream branch it is already set to track, and you don't have to specify the remote name nor branch name manually each time. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5555118/4561887).

Answer (score 483):

### On init running the following command:

```
git submodule update --init --remote --recursive
```

from within the git repo directory, works best for me.

This will pull all latest including submodules.

### Explained

```
git - the base command to perform any git command
    submodule - Inspects, updates and manages submodules.
        update - Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject
        expects by cloning missing submodules and updating the working tree of the
        submodules. The "updating" can be done in several ways depending on command
        line options and the value of submodule.<name>.update configuration variable.
            --init without the explicit init step if you do not intend to customize
            any submodule locations.
            --recursive is specified, this command will recurse into the registered
            submodules, and update any nested submodules within.
```

---

### After this you can just run:

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

from within the git repo directory, works best for me.

This will pull all latest including submodules.

Comment: Yes -- the highest voted answer was the best way to do it in '09, but this is definitely simpler and more intuitive now.

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert thanks, i'm sure in another 3 years this command will be crazy too

Comment: Nevertheless, this does not checkout the latest revision from the submodule, only the latest revision that the parent is tracking.

Comment: @NathanOsman which is what you want...you will end up with broken code by not following the parents revision tracking.  If you are the maintainer of the parent you can update those yourself and commit them.

Comment: Yes, but from my understanding, that isn't what the OP wanted.

Comment: This only works for the initial checkout, it doesn't help with updating to the latest version of the submodule if its your own project, which is the case of the OP.

Comment: This answer works for me. I am using `git version 2.17.2`.

Comment: `git submodule update --recursive --remote --init` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 325):

**Note: This is from 2009 and may have been good then but there are better options now.**

We use this.  It's called `git-pup`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Exists to fully update the git repo that you are sitting in...

git pull && git submodule init && git submodule update && git submodule status
```

Just put it in a suitable bin directory (/usr/local/bin).  If on Windows, you may need to modify the syntax to get it to work :)

**Update:**

In response to the comment by the original author about pulling in all of the HEADs of all of the submodules -- that is a good question.

I am pretty sure that `git` does not have a command for this internally.  In order to do so, you would need to identify what HEAD really is for a submodule.  That could be as simple as saying `master` is the most up to date branch, etc...

Following this, create a simple script that does the following:

1. check `git submodule status` for "modified" repositories.  The first character of the output lines indicates this.  If a sub-repo is modified, you may NOT want to proceed.
2. for each repo listed, cd into it's directory and run `git checkout master && git pull`.  Check for errors.
3. At the end, I suggest you print a display to the user to indicate the current status of the submodules -- perhaps prompt them to add all and commit?

I'd like to mention that this style is not really what git submodules were designed for.  Typically, you want to say "LibraryX" is at version "2.32" and will stay that way until I tell it to "upgrade".

That is, in a sense, what you are doing with the described script, but just more automatically.  Care is required!

**Update 2:**

If you are on a windows platform, you may want to look at using Python to implement the script as it is very capable in these areas.  If you are on unix/linux, then I suggest just a bash script.

Need any clarifications?  Just post a comment.

Comment: I don't think that's what I want. Won't that pull the version of the submodules that the super-project was last committed with.  I want to pull the head version of all the submodules.

Comment: This works great, and works not only to update the submodules but also to fetch them for the first time if that's what you need.

Comment: I'm just getting "There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with." No matter what I try :/

Comment: Why not create an alias for it? `git config --global alias.pup '!git pull && git submodule init && git submodule update && git submodule status'` and then use it as `git pup` without any scripting.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason even though I have git 1.9.1 I had to perform `git submodule init` after first pull that had submodules included, so that everything would start working properly.

Comment: "git pull && git submodule init && git submodule update && git submodule status" can be executed on console in Windows as well (for example in far manager)

Comment: I think this one doesn't work correctly whenever submodules are removed in the newly checked out commit.

Answer (score 205):

[Henrik is on the right track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032653/4561887).  The `git submodule foreach` command can execute any arbitrary shell script.  Two options to pull the very latest might be:

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

and:

```
git submodule foreach /path/to/some/cool/script.sh
```

That will iterate through all *initialized* submodules and run the given commands.

Comment: Nice! This is perhaps the best answer! If your subrepo contains subrepos, however, you'll want to add `--recusrive` too, like this: `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master`. See `man git submodule` and search for the section which says `foreach [--recursive] <command>`, for details.

Answer (score 151):

The following worked for me on Windows.

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Comment: This clearly is not what the OP asked for. It will only update to the associated submodule commit and not the latest one.

Comment: This is however the only thing on this page that got git to pull submodules the first time I checked out a repo

Comment: Can also use: git submodule update --init --recursive (particularly if the submodule in question is RestKit from a fresh clone)

Comment: I needed to init first. Thanks

Answer (score 50):

For me, git 2.24.03, get updated to latest commit of remote branches defined in *.gitmodules*.

`git submodule update --recursive --init`

`git submodule update --recursive --remote`

git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)

**Please Note:**
Someone said that
`git pull --recurse-submodules`is the same as `git submodule update --recursive --remote`. But from my test, `git pull --recurse-submodules` may not get updated to latest commit of remote branches defined in *.gitmodules*.

Comment: do you know why the 2nd command is needed with --remote?

Comment: this works with the --init thanks

Answer (score 44):

### First time

Clone and Init Submodule

```
git clone git@github.com:speedovation/kiwi-resources.git resources
git submodule init
```

### Rest

During development just pull and update submodule

```
git pull --recurse-submodules  && git submodule update --recursive
```

### Update Git submodule to latest commit on origin

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

#### Preferred way should be below

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

*note: last two commands have same behaviour*

Comment: I did a git clone with no submodules by mistake and all other options didn't worked, no one did clone submodules. Using yours, `git submodule update` did the trick. Now I'm downloading submodules data missing from the clone first step. Thank you. I'm not good at git :C

Comment: This anser is actually a very good answer to ask a question here on top: why do I have to ".. --recursive-submodules.." and then additionally the "... update ..." _and_ even "...foreach..." later to get latest commit? All this does not look GIT like at all! What is "update" doing and why do I have to manually go to each module to pull? Isn't that what "... --recurse-submodules .." is doing? Any hints?

Answer (score 41):

**Edit**:

In the comments was pointed out (by **philfreo** ) that the latest version is required. If there is any nested submodules that need to be in their latest version :

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git pull
```

**-----Outdated comment below-----**

Isn't this the official way to do it ?

```
git submodule update --init
```

I use it every time. No problems so far.

**Edit:**

I just found that you can use:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git submodule update --init
```

Which will also recursively pull all of the submodules, i.e. dependancies.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the OP's question, but to do what you've proposed you can just say `git submodule update --init --recursive`

Comment: I see, latest version is needed. Well this might be usefull if there is nested submodules: `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull`

Comment: I couldn't make any of these actually download anything -- "git submodule update --init --recursive" worked for me however.

Answer (score 40):

As it may happens that the default branch of your submodules is **not** `master`, this is how I automate the full Git submodules upgrades:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
git submodule foreach 'git fetch origin; git checkout $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git reset --hard origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git submodule update --recursive; git clean -dfx'
```

Comment: out of the many answers to the many questions, this one worked for me (2019, github error with specific hash ids)

Comment: This is what I've been looking for as I have submodules with `master` and `main`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I don't know since which version of git this is working, but that's what you're searching for:

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

I use it with `git pull` to update the root repository, too:

```
git pull && git submodule update --recursive
```

Answer (score 18):

The above answers are good, however we were using git-hooks to make this easier but it turns out that in **git 2.14**, you can set [`git config submodule.recurse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-submodulerecurse) to true to enable submodules to to updated when you pull to your git repository.

This will have the side effect of pushing all submodules change you have if they are on branches however, but if you have need of that behaviour already this could do the job.

Can be done by using:

```
git config submodule.recurse true
```

Comment: Gotta love this option, unfortunately still need to use ```git submodule init``` before hand though if your submodule isn't yet initialized.

Answer (score 17):

To clarify a few things based on already available answers of pulling "**latest**" code of each submodule from remote.

If "**latest**" means the submodule pointers that were checked in, then by all means use:

```
git submodule update --recursive
  - or -
git pull --recurse-submodules --jobs=X
```

If "**latest**" means the latest of **main**, then something like this can work:

```
git submodule foreach "git checkout main && git pull"
```

Unfortunately, this means there's no "--jobs" option, so we cannot run it in parallel.  The closest I've seen to running this in parallel is by using the [pfs](https://pypi.org/project/pfs/) python code.

Answer (score 15):

I often use this commands, it works so far.

```
git pull
git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout master
git submodule foreach --recursive git pull
```

Hope this faster.

Answer (score 11):

As noted in [antitoxic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/339872/antitoxic)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5555118), a simple `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull` can be enough.

[Francis Bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5097539/francis-bacon)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66928886) notes `git pull --recurse-submodules` can differ.

You could test out and see what is going on with a verbose option:

```
git pull -v --recurse-submodules
```

But for that, you will need Git 2.40 (Q1 2023).

"[`git pull -v --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b3b9e5c1718e59d2a835291bbc9c28b1762c45ce/Documentation/git-pull.txt#L86)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--v))</sup> attempted to pass `-v` down to underlying [`git submodule update`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b3b9e5c1718e59d2a835291bbc9c28b1762c45ce/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L136)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N%7C--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f%7C--force--checkout%7C--rebase%7C--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--filterltfilterspecgt--ltpathgt82308203))</sup>, which did not understand the request and barfed: this has been corrected with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023).

See [commit 6f65f84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f65f847664445b347810bece6eee84c2f39f4ef) (10 Dec 2022) by [Sven Strickroth (`csware`)](https://github.com/csware).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b3b9e5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3b9e5c1718e59d2a835291bbc9c28b1762c45ce), 28 Dec 2022)</sup>

> ### [`submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f65f847664445b347810bece6eee84c2f39f4ef): accept `-v` for the update command
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sven Strickroth</sup>

> Since [a56771a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a56771a668dd4963675914bc5da0e1e015952dae) ("`builtin/pull`: respect verbosity settings in submodules", 2018-01-25, Git v2.17.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/157ee050615192d579a358723563e7f785d676ff) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f9c1fab6421402a9c893a2fcd35fb4cf6116166)), "[`git pull -v --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6f65f847664445b347810bece6eee84c2f39f4ef/Documentation/git-pull.txt#L86)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--v))</sup> propagates the `-v` to the submodule command, but because the latter command does not understand the option, it barfs.
>
> Teach "[`git submodule update`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6f65f847664445b347810bece6eee84c2f39f4ef/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L136)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N%7C--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f%7C--force--checkout%7C--rebase%7C--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--filterltfilterspecgt--ltpathgt82308203))</sup> to accept the option to fix it.

No more "barfing" (IE. displaying the usage '`git submodule foreach [--quiet] [--recursive] [--] <command>`') because the `-v` was an unknown option for `git submodule`.

Answer (score 7):

Git for windows **2.6.3**:

`git submodule update --rebase --remote`

Comment: That's the only one that worked for me. I wasn't even able to init or update as the submodule pointer was pointing to a version that wasn't in the remote anymore

Answer (score 5):

From the top level in the repo:

```
git submodule foreach git checkout develop
git submodule foreach git pull
```

This will switch all branches to develop and pull latest

Comment: Do you have something like an Everything sln file which adds all the project references in the tree? Also what error do you see? Can you check your gitignore file too

Comment: `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` Had to append the branch I wanted to fetch. other than that, worked perfectly.

Comment: You may want to add `--recursive` as well in order to recurse down into submodules within submodules. Ex: `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull`

Answer (score 3):

*I did this by adapting [gahooa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64004/gahooa)'s [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030263/1886534):*

Integrate it with a git `[alias]` ...

If your parent project has something like this in `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "opt/submodules/solarized"]
    path = opt/submodules/solarized
    url = git@github.com:altercation/solarized.git
[submodule "opt/submodules/intellij-colors-solarized"]
    path = opt/submodules/intellij-colors-solarized
    url = git@github.com:jkaving/intellij-colors-solarized.git
```

Add something like this inside your .gitconfig

```
[alias]
    updatesubs = "!sh -c \"git submodule init && git submodule update && git submodule status\" "
```

Then to update your submodules, run:

```
git updatesubs
```

I have an [example](https://github.com/wheelertom/my-env/blob/master/conf/git/gitconfig) of it in my [environment setup repo](https://github.com/wheelertom/my-env).

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do now is a simple `git checkout`

Just make sure to enable it via this global config: `git config --global submodule.recurse true`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the command-line to pull from all of your git repositories whether they're or not submodules:

```
ROOT=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2> /dev/null)
find "$ROOT" -name .git -type d -execdir git pull -v ';'
```

If you running it in your top git repository, you can replace `"$ROOT"` into `.`.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on this simple shell script which works fine for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

#git init
git init

#git clone repo including submodules
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/username/project.git

#change directory -repo
cd project

#update the remote ie tag/commits
git submodule update --remote

#add commit 
git commit -a -m "commit in submodule"

#git push 
git push -u origin
```

Answer (score 1):

Remark: not too easy way, but workable and it has its own unique pros.

If one want to clone only `HEAD` revision of a repository and only `HEAD`s of all the its submodules (i.e. to checkout "trunk"), then one can use following *Lua* script. Sometimes simple command `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote --no-fetch --depth=1` can result in an unrecoverable `git` error. In this case one need to clean up subdirectory of `.git/modules` directory and clone submodule manually using `git clone --separate-git-dir` command. The only complexity is to find out *URL*, path of `.git` directory of submodule and path of submodule in superproject tree.

Remark: the script is only tested against `https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git` repository. Its peculiarities: all the submodules hosted on the same host and `.gitmodules` contains only relative *URL*s.

```
-- mkdir boost ; cd boost ; lua ../git-submodules-clone-HEAD.lua https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git .
local module_url = arg[1] or 'https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git'
local module = arg[2] or module_url:match('.+/([_%d%a]+)%.git')
local branch = arg[3] or 'master'
function execute(command)
    print('# ' .. command)
    return os.execute(command)
end
-- execute('rm -rf ' .. module)
if not execute('git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 ' .. module_url .. ' ' .. module) then
    io.stderr:write('can\'t clone repository from ' .. module_url .. ' to ' .. module .. '\n')
    return 1
end
-- cd $module ; git submodule update --init --recursive --remote --no-fetch --depth=1
execute('mkdir -p ' .. module .. '/.git/modules')
assert(io.input(module .. '/.gitmodules'))
local lines = {}
for line in io.lines() do
    table.insert(lines, line)
end
local submodule
local path
local submodule_url
for _, line in ipairs(lines) do
    local submodule_ = line:match('^%[submodule %"([_%d%a]-)%"%]$')
    if submodule_ then
        submodule = submodule_
        path = nil
        submodule_url = nil
    else
        local path_ = line:match('^%s*path = (.+)$')
        if path_ then
            path = path_
        else
            submodule_url = line:match('^%s*url = (.+)$')
        end
        if submodule and path and submodule_url then
            -- execute('rm -rf ' .. path)
            local git_dir = module .. '/.git/modules/' .. path:match('^.-/(.+)$')
            -- execute('rm -rf ' .. git_dir)
            execute('mkdir -p $(dirname "' .. git_dir .. '")')
            if not execute('git clone --depth=1 --single-branch --branch=' .. branch .. ' --separate-git-dir ' .. git_dir .. ' ' .. module_url .. '/' .. submodule_url .. ' ' .. module .. '/' .. path) then
                io.stderr:write('can\'t clone submodule ' .. submodule .. '\n')
                return 1
            end
            path = nil
            submodule_url = nil
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to write a script to do this. To be honest, I might install python to do it so that you can use `os.walk` to `cd` to each directory and issue the appropriate commands. Using python or some other scripting language, other than batch, would allow you to easily add/remove subprojects with out having to modify the script.