# Run git pull over all subdirectories

Tags: git, bash

How can I update  multiple git repositories from their shared parent's directory without `cd`'ing into each repo's root directory? I have the following which are all separate git repositories (**not** submodules):

```
/plugins/cms
/plugins/admin
/plugins/chart
```

I want to update them all at once or at least simplify my current workflow:

```
cd ~/plugins/admin
git pull origin master
cd ../chart
git pull
```

etc.

Comment: What's wrong with `find -name .git -execdir git pull \;`?

Comment: what about `git do pull`

Comment: The same question [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48790388/2192488) for `hg mercurial`.

Comment: `find . -name .git -print -execdir git pull \;`  is OK. `-print` will echo the current dir.

Comment: See also, with Git 2.30 (Q4 2020), the [new `git for-each-repo` command] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65766304/6309)

Comment: https://github.com/earwig/git-repo-updater — *“gitup is a tool for updating multiple git repositories at once. It is smart enough to handle several remotes, dirty working directories, diverged local branches, detached HEADs, and more. It was originally created to manage a large collection of projects and deal with sporadic internet access. gitup should work on macOS, Linux, and Windows. You should have the latest version of git and either Python 2.7 or Python 3 installed.”*

Answer (score 439, accepted):

Run the following from the parent directory, `plugins` in this case:

```
find . -type d -depth 1 -exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} pull origin master \;
```

To clarify:

- `find .` searches the current directory
- `-type d` to find directories, not files
- `-depth 1` for a maximum depth of one sub-directory
- `-exec {} \;` runs a custom command for every find
- `git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} pull` git pulls the individual directories

To play around with find, I recommend using `echo` after `-exec` to preview, e.g.:

```
find . -type d -depth 1 -exec echo git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} status \;
```

Note: if the `-depth 1` option is not available, try `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`.

Comment: Thanks @batandwa for your remark about the use of -d.

Comment: find: warning: you have specified the -depth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-depth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Comment: I used `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print -execdir git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} pull origin master \;` to output the name of the folder before doing the pull, to get rid of the warning and to only run the pull on subfolders.

Comment: replacing 'pull origin master' with `fetch origin master:master` tells git to explicitly update your 'master' branch with origin's master branch. This **will not do a merge**, any commits to master will be lost if you do this.

Comment: since git 1.8.5 it is possible to replace --git-dir and --work-tree by the -C option, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory). -- I'm using `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print -exec git -C {} pull \;`

Comment: Didnt´t work unfortunately: "find: warning: you have specified the -depth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-depth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments. find: paths must precede expression: 1
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
"

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy as mentioned by @Rystraum you can use `-maxdepth 1` instead of `-depth 1`

Comment: Note that when using this solution for bare repositories you have to omit --work-tree and leave only --git-dir, i.e.

`find . -type d -depth 1 -exec echo git --git-dir={}/ remote update \;`

Comment: I use this to avoid hidden folders `find . -not -path '*/\.*' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print -exec git -C {} pull \;`

Comment: Can we make each `git pull` run in parallel?

Comment: Also all the spaces in this line are sensitive I found out.

Comment: After following some of the comments that explain that depth has changed to maxdepth, I get an error 'missing argument to -exec'.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this is what I came up with: 

find . -type d -name ".git" \
    -a -exec echo {} \; \
    -exec git --git-dir={} --work-tree=$PWD/{}/../ status \; \
    -exec git --git-dir={} --work-tree=$PWD/{}/../ pull \; \
    -exec git --git-dir={} --work-tree=$PWD/{}/../ fetch -ap \;

Comment: depending on how you use,  you might add --rebase: 

`find . -type d -depth 1 -exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} pull --rebase origin master \;`

Answer (score 309):

```
ls | xargs -I{} git -C {} pull
```

To do it in parallel:

```
ls | xargs -P10 -I{} git -C {} pull
```

Comment: Nice! I've put it as an alias in my .gitconfig: `all = "!f() { ls | xargs -I{} git -C {} $1; }; f"` Now I can do `git all pull`, `git all "checkout master"` etc.

Comment: Cleaned up a bit, will search all directories recursively for only git repos, and will strip out colors in case you have ls aliased `ls -R --directory --color=never */.git | sed 's/\/.git//' | xargs -P10 -I{} git -C {} pull`

Comment: Here's the git config command to add it as an alias: git config --global alias.all '!f() { ls | xargs -I{} git -C {} $1; }; f'

Comment: I smashed some of the answers together to create this for git on macOS that filters on folder that contain a .git folder, and lets you run arbitrary commands like `git all fetch --prune`: `git config --global alias.all '!f() { ls -R -d */.git | sed 's,\/.git,,' | xargs -P10 -I{} git -C {} $1; }; f'`

Comment: @CourtneyFaulkner This looks like it assumes a .git directory is available where the command is run. Am I right? Seems different from the original question where just the subdirectories contain .git dirs.

Comment: @AWrightIV actually, `ls -R -d */.git` is returning a filtered list of the directories within the current folder that contain a `.git` directory. That way, when I run something like `git all fetch`, it only executes against subfolders that have .git folders. It's an answer to the original question, but it tries to be a bit more efficient by not assuming all the subdirectories are git repos.

Comment: A slight improvement over borisdiakur command, to avoid running on `.` and to have a printed list of on which directory it's running at each instant: 
`git config --global alias.all '!f() { ls -R -d */.git | xargs -I{} bash -c "echo {} && git -C {}/../ $1"; }; f'`

Comment: @borisdiakur Is there a trick to run the pull in parallel in all directories ?

Comment: I'm getting xargs: unknown option -- C

Comment: If you want to avoid non git directories it will be 
```bash 
ls -R -d */.git | cut -d'.' -f1 | xargs -I{} git -C {} pull
```

Comment: Why this answer isn't on top?

Comment: this answer is the best:
`ls | xargs -P10 -I{} git -C {} pull`

Answer (score 128):

A bit more low-tech than leo's solution:

```
for i in */.git; do ( echo $i; cd $i/..; git pull; ); done
```

This will update all Git repositories in your working directory. No need to explicitly list their names ("cms", "admin", "chart"). The "cd" command only affects a subshell (spawned using the parenthesis).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: This one has the advantage of displaying which repository it is dealing with, usefeul when something goes wrong (missing branch, un-available remote..)

Comment: This worked great. I added a crontab -e file to run this every 5 minutes and it appears to do exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: You inspired me. Many thanks.

Comment: I like this solution because it only pulls on sub-directories that are a git repo, thx!

Comment: Alternate using `git -C`: `for i in */.git; do git -C $i pull; done`

Comment: Is there any way to automate typing in the username and password for each subfolder repo?

Comment: @colinodowd: Yes :-) This is independent of this one-liner; you'll have to tell git about the credentials in each individual case. How this is done depends on whether you're accessing your repos using https or ssh.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Thanks Ingo, I figured it out through another SO thread :-) I love how automated my process is now!

Comment: This is the most straightforward solution IMO. Just add a '&' to the end of git pull to make it async so you're not waiting for each pull to complete before looping to the next item: `for i in */.git; do ( echo $i; cd $i/..; git pull &) ; done`

Comment: Simply, easy, working and easily configurable. THX!

Answer (score 58):

Actually, if you don't know if the subfolders have a git repo or not, the best would be to let `find` get the repos for you:

```
find . -type d -name .git -exec git --git-dir={} --work-tree=$PWD/{}/.. pull origin master \;
```

The PowerShell equivalent would be:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Hidden -Filter .git | ForEach-Object { & git --git-dir="$($_.FullName)" --work-tree="$(Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent)" pull origin master }
```

Comment: This works with my macOS.

Comment: Ensure all your git repos are on master before executing this as written. Otherwise you may be unintentionally merging master into your current branch.

Comment: Thank you for the powershell version, still works with PS 7.10

Comment: For PS 2.0 this works: ```gci | where {$_.Attributes -match'Directory'} | foreach { write-host $_.fullname; push-location $_; & git pull; & cd ..}```

Comment: Note - I could not find a `hidden` parameter, but `Force` seemed to work, as in `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Repos" -Recurse -Directory -Force -Filter ".git" -Depth 1`

Comment: Is there a way to have it act on either master or main based on whichever is used?

Answer (score 33):

I use this one:

```
find . -name ".git" -type d | sed 's/\/.git//' |  xargs -P10 -I{} git -C {} pull
```

Universal: Updates all git repositories that are below current directory.

Comment: It's dangerous to use `--git-dir` without `--work-tree` which is why the `-C` shortcut was created. I just messed up my home directory because of this. I would recommend just doing `find . -maxdepth 8 -type d -name .git | xargs  -P8 -I{} git -C {}/../ fetch --all`

Answer (score 16):

None of the top 5 answers worked for me, and the question talked about directories.

This worked:

```
for d in *; do pushd $d && git pull && popd; done
```

Comment: For Windows, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51016478/207661. It's very similar to above.

Comment: The accepted answer used to work for me, but it quit sometime in the last year. I finally decided to look for another solution and found your answer. Thanks for sharing. It works perfectly.

Comment: no need to push and pup, just use git's `-C` option.

Comment: Another option is to use a subshell: `for d in *; do (cd $d && git pull --ff-only); done` This has an advantage over -C as this approach is universally applicable to programs which don't have such option. Note that `--ff-only` is good to have in case of automatic updates; I use it to update vim plugins if native vim package management is used.

Answer (score 14):

This should happen automatically, so long as cms, admin and chart are all parts of the repository.

A likely issue is that each of these plugins is a git submodule.

Run `git help submodule` for more information.

**EDIT**

For doing this in bash:

```
cd plugins
for f in cms admin chart
do 
  cd $f && git pull origin master && cd ..
done
```

Comment: No, sorry you misunderstood. Each of those directories are a separate git repository. `/plugins` is not a repository

Comment: Ahhh. My mistake. Will give you the bash solution in a minute.

Comment: There you go. If you want to return to the parent directory, just run another `cd ..` afterwards.

Comment: Or use `pushd` and `popd` or put the group of commands in a subshell (when the subshell exits, you'll be left in the original directory). `(cd dir; for ... done)`

Comment: Cool, that works. Now is there a way to pass the ssh password to the bash script and have the script pass it to git/ssh instead of prompting every time for my password?

Comment: Out of curiousity - why are aren't you using ssh keys instead?

Answer (score 12):

The `mr` utility (a.k.a., [`myrepos`](https://myrepos.branchable.com/)) provides an *outstanding* solution to this very problem. Install it using your favorite package manager, or just grab the `mr` script [directly from github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joeyh/myrepos/master/mr) and put it in `$HOME/bin` or somewhere else on your `PATH`. Then, `cd` to the parent `plugins` folder shared by these repos and create a basic `.mrconfig` file with contents similar to the following (adjusting the URLs as needed):

```
# File: .mrconfig
[cms]
checkout = git clone 'https://<username>@github.com/<username>/cms' 'cms'

[admin]
checkout = git clone 'https://<username>@github.com/<username>/admin' 'admin'

[chart]
checkout = git clone 'https://<username>@github.com/<username>/chart' 'chart'
```

After that, you can run `mr up` from the top level `plugins` folder to pull updates from each repository. (Note that this will also do the initial clone if the target working copy doesn't yet exist.) Other commands you can execute include `mr st`, `mr push`, `mr log`, `mr diff`, etc—run `mr help` to see what's possible. There's a `mr run` command that acts as a pass-through, allowing you to access VCS commands not directly suported by `mr` itself (e.g., `mr run git tag STAGING_081220015`). And you can even create your own custom commands that execute arbitrary bits of shell script targeting all repos!

`mr` is an extremely useful tool for dealing with multiple repos. Since the `plugins` folder is in your home directory, you might also be interested in [`vcsh`](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh). Together with `mr`, it provides a powerful mechanism for managing *all* of your configuration files. See this [blog post](http://blog.tfnico.com/2014/03/managing-dot-files-with-vcsh-and-myrepos.html) by Thomas Ferris Nicolaisen for an overview.

Answer (score 12):

Most compact method, assuming all sub-dirs are git repos:

```
ls | parallel git -C {} pull
```

Comment: can't find command `parallel`. reference?

Comment: @LeonTepe This tool is usually included with `moreutils` package.

Answer (score 11):

My humble construction that

- shows the current path (using python, convenient and just works, see [How to get full path of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file))
- looks directly for `.git` subfolder: low chance to emit a git command in a non-git subfolder
- gets rid of some warnings of `find`

as follow:

```
find . \
    -maxdepth 2 -type d \
    -name ".git" \
    -execdir python -c 'import os; print(os.path.abspath("."))' \; \
    -execdir git pull \;
```

Of course, you may add other git commands with additional `-execdir` options to `find`, displaying the branch for instance:

```
find . \
    -maxdepth 2 -type d \
    -name ".git" \
    -execdir python -c 'import os; print(os.path.abspath("."))' \; \
    -execdir git branch \;
    -execdir git pull \;
```

Comment: Not sure why there's net downvotes on this answer. This was the most helpful, imo, since I could go to a greater max depth and not keep hitting non-git repos. I used this to run git gc on all all the repositories in my "developer" repo.

Comment: I also like this answer as it's easy to read and very easy to add multiple commands.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
find . -type d -name .git -exec sh -c "cd \"{}\"/../ && pwd && git pull" \;
```

Also, you can add your customized output by adding one more && argument like.

```
find . -type d -name .git -exec sh -c "cd \"{}\"/../ && pwd && git pull && git status" \;
```

Answer (score 5):

`gitfox` is a tool to execute command on all subrepos

```
npm install gitfox -g
g pull
```

Comment: what's `g`? not everyone has the same alias as yours

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc gitfox installs itself under the alias "g" for some reason (though the help message says "gitfox"). Personally I do not think it's a command important enough to claim such a shortcut but ah well. It does the job, though.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Check the source repo for the usage https://github.com/eqfox/gitfox

Answer (score 5):

I combined points from several comments and answers:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name .git -execdir git pull \;
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this

```
for dir in $(find . -name ".git")
do cd ${dir%/*}
    echo $PWD
    git pull
    echo ""
    cd - > /dev/null
done
```

[Github](https://github.com/pangteypiyush/git-batch-pull/blob/master/batch-pull.sh)

Answer (score 0):

Original answer 2010:

If all of those directories are separate git repo, you should reference them as **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)**.

That means your "origin" would be that remote repo '`plugins`' which only contains references to subrepos '`cms`', '`admin`', '`chart`'.

A `git pull` followed by a `git submodule update` would achieve what your are looking for.

---

Update January 2016:

With Git 2.8 (Q1 2016), you will be able to fetch submodules in parallel (!) with `git fetch --recurse-submodules -j2`.
See "[How to speed up / parallelize downloads of git submodules using git clone --recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762036/6309)"

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/git-easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules: `git submodule foreach git pull` can also be of interest.

Comment: Note: to clarify, '`plugins`', which is not a git repo at the moment, should be made one, as a parent git repo for the submodules.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a lot of subdirs with git repositories, you can use parallel

```
ls | parallel -I{} -j100 '
  if [ -d {}/.git ]; then
    echo Pulling {}
    git -C {} pull > /dev/null && echo "pulled" || echo "error :("
  else
     echo {} is not a .git directory
  fi
'
```

Comment: Great one. I modified a bit to suit my style. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/U7SMszkP)