# How to get full path of a file?

Tags: linux, file, unix, path

Is there an easy way I can print the full path of `file.txt` ?

```
file.txt = /nfs/an/disks/jj/home/dir/file.txt
```

The `<command>`

```
dir> <command> file.txt
```

should print

```
/nfs/an/disks/jj/home/dir/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1693, accepted):

Use [**readlink**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html):

```
readlink -f file.txt
```

Comment: I guess this works only for symbolic links..<br>Usage: readlink FILE
  If FILE exists and is a symlink, print the contents of the link and  exit successfully.  Otherwise print nothing and fail.

--help      display this help and exit
--version   output version information and exit

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac

Comment: on mas osx it returns -f is illegal and proposed to use -n instead but returned nothing.

Comment: This is true, but has been observed before. Have a look at the link that I posted for Mac OS X (and possibly other in-the-wild implementations of `readlink`).

Comment: Just tested on 10.9.2, works fine.
which readlink
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/readlink
readlink --version
readlink (GNU coreutils) 8.22

Comment: @J0hnG4lt: that's because you installed coreutils with homebrew and changed your PATH to point to the unprefixed binaries. Installing coreutils, leaving PATH alone, and using "greadlink" would work as well.

Comment: Warning: this will print the target of a symbolic link if the argument is a symbolic link. So this solution does not work with symbolic links. ZeRemz's answer works

Comment: @filmor The `-f` is for full path. Works well in Linux, and the asker was using linux... hence why this is the correct answer.

Comment: on MAC: install homebrew then `brew install coreutils` then `greadlink -f file.txt`

Comment: readlink doesn't exist on AIX (IBM Unix) and probably not other other *nixes either

Comment: From the man page of `readlink`: Note `realpath` is the preferred command to use for canonicalization functionality.

Comment: This answer has methods for both linux and windows https://stackoverflow.com/a/45690418/6665568

Comment: Works great for both relative (./file.txt) and absolut path (/home/user/file.txt)!

Comment: macOS 12.3 [added support](https://scriptingosx.com/2022/03/some-cli-updates-in-macos-monterey/) for `readlink -f`.

Comment: It's better to use `realpath -s file-or-dir` or `realpath --no-symlinks file-or-dir` since the question is about how to get the full/absolute path of a file and not about [how to get the target of symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7665/9157799)

Answer (score 411):

I suppose you are using Linux.

I found a utility called `realpath` in coreutils 8.15.

```
realpath -s file.txt
/data/ail_data/transformed_binaries/coreutils/test_folder_realpath/file.txt
```

Since the question is about how to get the full/absolute path of a file and not about [how to get the target of symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7665/9157799), use `-s` or `--no-symlinks` which means don't expand symlinks.

As per @styrofoam-fly and @arch-standton comments, `realpath` alone doesn't check for file existence, to solve this add the `e` argument: `realpath -e file`

Comment: Works with cygwin (with mintty 2.7.9)

Comment: `realpath` was committed to the coreutils repo end of 2011, release 8.15 was done in January 2012, I answered the question (with the `readlink` suggestion) in March 2011 :)

Comment: realpath doesn't check for the file's existence, it just resolves paths. Asking for a full path of a not existing file should result in an error.

Comment: @styrofoamfly `realpath -e` prints an error if the argument doesn't exist.

Comment: This is better than readlink since you can get the full path of files AND folders!

Comment: Add the `-s` option to not expand symlinks.

Comment: It's work for me with argument -q. Full command: realpath -q file_name

Answer (score 102):

The following usually does the trick:

```
 echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")" && pwd -P)/$(basename "$1")"
```

Comment: Hello. I found this answer best to my requirement. Can you explain how can I use a local variable instead of command line parameter(i.e. $1)

Comment: `LOCAL_VARIABLE="filename.txt" &&
echo $(cd $(dirname "$LOCAL_VARIABLE") && pwd -P)/$(basename "$LOCAL_VARIABLE")`

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Because `readlink` doesn't work if the file is a symlink, it will show you the target of the symlink instead of the symlink itself.

Comment: I  like this, because `readlink` takes me back to the parent dir where the symbolic link generates from, but this ignores it.

Comment: `set .. && echo $(cd $(dirname "$1") && pwd -P)/$(basename "$1")`
   ### Output:  /home/ravi/..

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer because of its portability.

Answer (score 51):

I *know* there's an easier way that this, but darned if I can find it...

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ python -c 'import os; print(os.path.abspath("cat.wav"))'
/home/jcomeau/cat.wav
```

---

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ ls $PWD/cat.wav
/home/jcomeau/cat.wav
```

Answer (score 47):

### On Windows:

- Holding `Shift` and right clicking on a file in Windows Explorer gives you an option called `Copy as Path`.
  This will copy the full path of the file to clipboard.

### On Linux:

- You can use the command `realpath yourfile` to get the full path of a file as suggested by others.

Answer (score 35):

```
find $PWD -type f | grep "filename"
```

or

```
find $PWD -type f -name "*filename*"
```

Comment: For me, on mac, this worked - instead of $pwd - `find \`pwd\` -type file -name \*.dmp`

Comment: Thanks! This inspired me to use a simpler `find $PWD` that works perfectly for me when it's just a few files

Answer (score 27):

If you are in the same directory as the file:

```
ls "`pwd`/file.txt"
```

Replace `file.txt` with your target filename.

Comment: you can also do `echo $(pwd)/file.txt`

Answer (score 7):

I know that this is an old question now, but just to add to the information here:

The Linux command `which` can be used to find the filepath of a command file, i.e.

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

There are some caveats to this; please see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-the-path-to-a-command-file/.

Comment: This answer is too specific, the OP is not about finding commands.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [fpn (full path name)](http://adamatan.github.io/bin-devils/#fpn) script:

```
% pwd
/Users/adamatan/bins/scripts/fpn

% ls
LICENSE   README.md fpn.py

% fpn *
/Users/adamatan/bins/scripts/fpn/LICENSE
/Users/adamatan/bins/scripts/fpn/README.md
/Users/adamatan/bins/scripts/fpn/fpn.py
```

`fpn` is not a standard Linux package, but it's [a free and open github project](https://github.com/adamatan/bin) and you [could set it up in a minute](http://adamatan.github.io/bin-devils/#setup).

Comment: Generally, `pwd` by itself should run fine on Linux and most other Unix-like OS environments.

Answer (score 4):

**Works on Mac, Linux, *nix:**

This will give you a quoted csv of all files in the current dir:

```
ls | xargs -I {} echo "$(pwd -P)/{}" | xargs | sed 's/ /","/g'
```

The output of this can be easily copied into a python list or any similar data structure.

Comment: prints current pwd path

Comment: Yes, comma separated full paths for all files in pwd, for a file just do ls 'filename' instead of just 'ls'.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $(cd $(dirname "$1") && pwd -P)/$(basename "$1")
```

This is explanation of what is going on at @ZeRemz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265862/4632019):

1. This script get relative path as argument `"$1"`
2. Then we get *dirname* part of that path (you can pass either dir or file to this script): `dirname "$1"`
3. Then we `cd "$(dirname "$1")` into this relative dir
4. `&& pwd -P` and get absolute path for it. `-P` option will avoid all symlinks
5. After that we append *basename* to absolute path: `$(basename "$1")`
6. As final step we `echo` it

Answer (score 3):

You may use this function. If the file name is given without relative path, then it is assumed to be present in the current working directory:

```
abspath() { old=`pwd`;new=$(dirname "$1");if [ "$new" != "." ]; then cd $new; fi;file=`pwd`/$(basename "$1");cd $old;echo $file; }
```

Usage:

```
$ abspath file.txt
/I/am/in/present/dir/file.txt
```

Usage with relative path:

```
$ abspath ../../some/dir/some-file.txt
/I/am/in/some/dir/some-file.txt
```

With spaces in file name:

```
$ abspath "../../some/dir/another file.txt"
/I/am/in/some/dir/another file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses commands that exist on Ubuntu 22.04, but generally exist on most other Linux distributions, unless they are just too hardcore for s'mores.

The shortest way to get the full path of a file on Linux or Mac is to use the `ls` command and the `PWD` environment variable.

```
<0.o> touch afile
<0.o> pwd
/adir
<0.o> ls $PWD/afile
/adir/afile
```

You can do the same thing with a directory variable of your own, say `d`.

```
<0.o> touch afile
<0.o> d=/adir
<0.o> ls $d/afile
/adir/afile
```

Notice that without flags `ls <FILE>` and `echo <FILE>` are equivalent (for valid names of files in the current directory), so if you're using `echo` for that, you can use `ls` instead if you want.

If the situation is reversed, so that you have the full path and want the filename, just use the `basename` command.

```
<0.o> touch afile
<0.o> basename $PWD/afile
afile
```

Answer (score 3):

I was surprised no one mentioned located.

If you have the `locate` package installed, you don't even need to be in the directory with the file of interest.

Say I am looking for the full pathname of a `setenv.sh` script.  This is how to find it.

```
$ locate setenv.sh
/home/davis/progs/devpost_aws_disaster_response/python/setenv.sh
/home/davis/progs/devpost_aws_disaster_response/webapp/setenv.sh
/home/davis/progs/eb_testy/setenv.sh
```

Note, it finds three scripts in this case, but if I wanted just one I
would do this:

```
$ locate *testy*setenv.sh
/home/davis/progs/eb_testy/setenv.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

In a similar scenario, I'm launching a cshell script from some other location. For setting the correct absolute path of the script so that it runs in the designated directory only, I'm using the following code:

```
set script_dir = `pwd`/`dirname $0`
```

`$0` stores the exact string how the script was executed.

For e.g. if the script was launched like this: `$> ../../test/test.csh`,
`$script_dir` will contain `/home/abc/sandbox/v1/../../test`

Comment: voted for this as this is the easiest and most relevant. However if you type `./test.csh` you will have a path ending with `/test/.`

Answer (score 2):

You can save this in your `shell.rc` or just put in console

```
function absolute_path { echo "$PWD/$1"; }
alias ap="absolute_path"
```

example:

```
ap somefile.txt
```

will output

```
/home/user/somefile.txt
```

Comment: But then `ap ../foobar.txt` will give `/home/user/../foobar.txt`, which is not generally what you want.

Comment: Also `ap /tmp/foobar.txt` will give `/home/user//tmp/foobar.txt`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac OS X, I replaced the utilities that come with the operating system and replaced them with a newer version of coreutils. This allows you to access tools like `readlink -f` (for absolute path to files) and `realpath` (absolute path to directories) on your Mac.

The Homebrew version appends a 'G' (for GNU Tools) in front of the command name -- so the equivalents become `greadlink -f FILE` and `grealpath DIRECTORY`.

Instructions for how to install the coreutils/GNU Tools on Mac OS X  through Homebrew can be found in [this StackExchange arcticle](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities).

NB: The `readlink -f` and `realpath` commands should work out of the box for non-Mac Unix users.

Comment: `brew install coreutils`

Answer (score 1):

I like many of the answers already given, but I have found this really useful, especially within a script to get the full path of a file, including following symlinks and relative references such as `.` and `..`

```
dirname `readlink -e relative/path/to/file`
```

Which will return the full path of the `file` from the root path onwards.
This can be used in a script so that the script knows which path it is running from, which is useful in a repository clone which could be located anywhere on a machine.

```
basePath=`dirname \`readlink -e $0\``
```

I can then use the `${basePath}` variable in my scripts to directly reference other scripts.

Hope this helps,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

This works with both Linux and Mac OSX:

```
echo $(pwd)$/$(ls file.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked pretty well for me.  It doesn't rely on the file system (a pro/con depending on need) so it'll be fast; and, it should be portable to most any *NIX.  It does assume the passed string is indeed relative to the PWD and not some other directory.

```
function abspath () {
   echo $1 | awk '\
      # Root parent directory refs to the PWD for replacement below
      /^\.\.\// { sub("^", "./") } \
      # Replace the symbolic PWD refs with the absolute PWD \
      /^\.\//   { sub("^\.", ENVIRON["PWD"])} \
      # Print absolute paths \
      /^\//   {print} \'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is naive, but I had to make it to be POSIX compliant. Requires permission to cd into the file's directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ${#} = 0 ]; then
  echo "Error: 0 args. need 1" >&2
  exit 1
fi


if [ -d ${1} ]; then


  # Directory


  base=$( cd ${1}; echo ${PWD##*/} )
  dir=$( cd ${1}; echo ${PWD%${base}} )

  if [ ${dir} = / ]; then
    parentPath=${dir}
  else
    parentPath=${dir%/}
  fi

  if [ -z ${base} ] || [ -z ${parentPath} ]; then
    if [ -n ${1} ]; then
      fullPath=$( cd ${1}; echo ${PWD} )
    else
      echo "Error: unsupported scenario 1" >&2
      exit 1
    fi
  fi

elif [ ${1%/*} = ${1} ]; then

  if [ -f ./${1} ]; then


    # File in current directory

    base=$( echo ${1##*/} )
    parentPath=$( echo ${PWD} )

  else
    echo "Error: unsupported scenario 2" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
elif [ -f ${1} ] && [ -d ${1%/*} ]; then


  # File in directory

  base=$( echo ${1##*/} )
  parentPath=$( cd ${1%/*}; echo ${PWD} )

else
  echo "Error: not file or directory" >&2
  exit 1
fi

if [ ${parentPath} = / ]; then
  fullPath=${fullPath:-${parentPath}${base}}
fi

fullPath=${fullPath:-${parentPath}/${base}}

if [ ! -e ${fullPath} ]; then
  echo "Error: does not exist" >&2
  exit 1
fi

echo ${fullPath}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for both file and folder:

```
getAbsolutePath(){
    [[ -d $1 ]] && { cd "$1"; echo "$(pwd -P)"; } || 
    { cd "$(dirname "$1")" || exit 1; echo "$(pwd -P)/$(basename "$1")"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually:

```
find `pwd` | grep <filename>
```

Alternatively, just for the current folder:

```
find `pwd` -maxdepth 1 | grep <filename>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
find / -samefile file.txt -print
```

Will find all the links to the file with the same **inode number** as file.txt

adding a `-xdev` flag will avoid `find` to cross device boundaries ("mount points"). (But this will probably cause nothing to be found if the `find` does not start at a directory on the same device as `file.txt`)

Do note that `find` can report multiple paths for a single filesystem object, because an Inode can be linked by more than one directory entry, possibly even using different names. For instance:

```
find /bin -samefile /bin/gunzip -ls
```

Will output:

```
12845178    4 -rwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         2251 feb  9  2012 /bin/uncompress
12845178    4 -rwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         2251 feb  9  2012 /bin/gunzip
```

Answer (score -1):

Another Linux utility, that does this job:

```
fname <file>
```

Answer (score -1):

For Mac OS, if you just want to get the path of a file in the finder, control click the file, and scroll down to "Services" at the bottom. You get many choices, including "copy path" and "copy full path". Clicking on one of these puts the path on the clipboard.

Answer (score -2):

```
fp () {
PHYS_DIR=`pwd -P`
RESULT=$PHYS_DIR/$1
echo $RESULT | pbcopy
echo $RESULT
}
```

Copies the text to your clipboard and displays the text on the terminal window.

:)

(I copied some of the code from another stack overflow answer but cannot find that answer anymore)

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way I found is:

```
for i in `ls`; do echo "`pwd`/$i"; done
```

It works well for me.

Answer (score -2):

In Mac OSX, do the following steps:

1. `cd` into the directory of the target file.
2. Type either of the following terminal commands.

Terminal

```
ls "`pwd`/file.txt"
echo $(pwd)/file.txt
```

3. Replace `file.txt` with your actual file name.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score -3):

Beside "readlink -f" , another commonly used command:

> ```
> $find  /the/long/path/but/I/can/use/TAB/to/auto/it/to/ -name myfile
> /the/long/path/but/I/can/use/TAB/to/auto/it/to/myfile
> $
> ```

This also give the full path and file name at console

Off-topic: This method just gives *relative* links, not absolute. The `readlink -f` command is the right one.

Answer (score -3):

Create a function like the below (echoes the absolute path of a file with pwd and adds the file at the end of the path:

```
abspath() { echo $(pwd "$1")/"$1"; }
```

Now you can just find any file path:

```
abspath myfile.ext
```

Answer (score -3):

This can be simplified

```
 ls <file_name> | pwd
```

Answer (score -3):

```
you@you:~/test$ ls
file
you@you:~/test$ path="`pwd`/`ls`"
you@you:~/test$ echo $path
/home/you/test/file
```

Answer (score -4):

To get full path of a file :

1) open your terminal **in the folder containing your file**, by pushing on the keyboard following keys:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

2) then type "pwd" (acronym of **P**rint name of **W**orking **D**irectory):

```
your@device ~ $ pwd
```

that's all folks!

Answer (score -5):

In mac mentioned below line works. No need to add any fancy lines.

```
> pwd filename
```

Comment: No it just prints the working directory (without the file name) as the name of the command suggests `print working directory`

Answer (score -10):

This will give you absolute path of the file:

```
find / -name file.txt
```

Comment: No, it will give the absolute path to every file on the filesystem of the same name, and take a long time to run.

Comment: @Deestan which is sometimes useful? Not really sure why this person's answer is so far downvoted, especially since it 1) answers the question 2) does not violate any of the asker's requirements, and 3) works in the case that you are not in the current working directory of the file. "It should only return ONE FILE PATH" was not in the asker's requirements.Why do you assume it would be? It turns out that this question is the one that came up when I wanted a full path for a file that was in a different working directory, and this answer does what I want. I'm sure there have been others like me.

Comment: @DragonBobZ It is a bit like answering the question, "How do I get rid of the mice in my house?" with "Napalm" Technically, that will work, I suppose.