# How to echo the current directory via . in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix

In Linux `.` is used to refer to the current directory, but I need to know instead using `pwd` what is the current directory via `.`.

I tried `echo $(.)` and`echo .` but doesn't work... any solution to get the same output as `pwd` but using `.`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get full path of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file)

Comment: `readlink -f .` works

Comment: `pwd` == `.`, it even expands `~` to a fully qualified path, what is your actual question? This is an [X - Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as stated.

Comment: Doing `echo $(pwd)` works fine, but a requiriment client is not use pwd, I need to use `.` to get the actual dir, but `echo $(.)` doesn't work. My question is how can i do an echo to get the value of `.`?

Comment: you use `echo \`pwd\``, you need to explain the requirement to use `.` it makes no sense technically or otherwise. `.` is just a short cut in the shell to `pwd`

Answer (score 1):

`readlink -f .`

would do the work