# How to get full path of a file from another directory in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I've a shell script at

```
/home/abc/xyz/test.sh
```

I've a file at

```
/home/def/ghi/jkl/lmn/foo.txt
```

I'm running the scrip from /home as I've set my `PATH` variable to point to `/home/abc/xyz/`

I'm passing the relative path of foo.txt to my script like so `test ./def/ghi/jkl/lmn/foo.txt`

I want to capture the full path of foo.txt into a **variable** in my script, any pointers?

Tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265775 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9107028/4468505 but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

```
foobar=`readlink -f <passed in relative path to foo.txt>`
```