# Linux find files and folders based on name length but output full path

Tags: linux, find

I have the following folder structure:

```
├── longdirectorywithsillylengththatyouwouldntnormallyhave
│   ├── asdasdads9ads9asd9asd89asdh9asd9asdh9asd
│   └── sinlf
└── shrtdir
    ├── nowthisisalongfile0000000000000000000000000
    └── sfile
```

I need to find files and folders where their names length is longer is than x characters. I have been able to achieve this with:

`find . -exec basename '{}' ';' | egrep '^.{20,}$'`

```
longdirectorywithsillylengththatyouwouldntnormallyhave
asdasdads9ads9asd9asd89asdh9asd9asdh9asd
nowthisisalongfile0000000000000000000000000
```

However, This only outputs the name of the file or folder in question. How can I output the full path of resulting matches like this:

```
/home/user/Desktop/longdirectorywithsillylengththatyouwouldntnormallyhave
/home/user/Desktop/longdirectorywithsillylengththatyouwouldntnormallyhave/asdasdads9ads9asd9asd89asdh9asd9asdh9asd
/home/user/Desktop/shrtdir/nowthisisalongfile0000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `basename` on your files, you lose the information about what file you are actually handling.

Therefore you have to change your regex to be able to recognize the length of the last path component.

The simplest way I could think of, would be:

```
find . | egrep '[^/]{20,}$' | xargs readlink -f
```

This makes use of the fact, that [filenames cannot contain slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename).

As the result then contains path relative to you current `cwd`, `readlink` to  [can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file) to give you the full path.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well an seemed to do what I needed. Out of interest, do you know if there is something similar that would work on macOS? The `-i` flag on `xargs` doesn't appear to be supported?

Comment: The `-i` is not necessary here - I edited the answer. This should be more portable.

Answer (score 0):

I cant test it right now but this should do the job:

```
find $(pwd) -exec basename '{}' ';' | egrep '^.{20,}$'
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but only appears to output the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -name "????????????????????*"  -printf "$PWD/%P\n"
```

The -printf option of find is very mighty. %P:

```
  %P     File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed. (%p starts with ./).
```

So we add $PWD/ in front.

```
/home/stefan/proj/mini/forum/tmp/Mo/shrtdir/nowthisisalongfile0000000000000000000000000
/home/stefan/proj/mini/forum/tmp/Mo/longdirectorywithsillylengththatyouwouldntnormallyhave
/home/stefan/proj/mini/forum/tmp/Mo/longdirectorywithsillylengththatyouwouldntnormallyhave/asdasdads9ads9asd9asd89asdh9asd9asdh9asd
```

To prevent us from manually counting question marks, we use:

```
for i in {1..20}; do echo -n "?" ; done; echo
????????????????????
```