# how i can change the default icon in the left of the window in Mac OS?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Now I want to design a simple game by using python, the step I want to do is to add an icon on the left of the window.
However, when I type

```
game_window.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')

game_window.mainloop()
```

the system just tell me Document Drag Error.
[image: Image of error]

I am sure I save favicon and the  both in the desktop and both of the path is correct.

I search this question in the internet but all of them are using window os.

Comment: try to set full path instead only filename. what you get then?

Comment: is the full path like this? ‘/Users/noahsark/Desktop/~/Desktop/favicon.ico’.

Comment: Linux [How to get full path of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file) is one way to get the path

Answer (score 0):

If your icon is in the same folder as your file, the script will surely work...

I think that you're getting the error because you didn't save the file you're working on for the first time.
Try the following:

Save your file in the same folder another time (if you've already done it).
If it doesn't work, then write the full path of the icon

Comment: well, I try also try to save them in the folder, but it still show the same error. Besides, I do not know how to write the full path of the icon. Is it like this? ‘/Users/noahsark/Desktop/~/Desktop/favicon.ico’