# node module not found .MODULE NOT FOUND

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, web-development-server

```
node app.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\app.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

i was trying to get the node code to work
basically node app.js

Comment: Did you do `npm install`?

Comment: Also, what is your `app.js` content? at least the imports.

Comment: Why do you put your code inside `node_modules`?

Answer (score 0):

Look into your project directory where you initialized `node app.js`. The issue is that you're not in the project directory where this file exists. Go into the project directory and launch your `node app.js`.

90% sure, hopefully this will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you're not in the right folder. Here you're in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` and you're trying to run your file `App.js` which is stored elsewhere on your computer.

I'd recommend going through these simple steps to fix the problem: (let's say you want `Node` to run your file `App.js`.

1. Check whether or not your file exist in the current working directory (the error says it isn't there) with one of the commands: 
   `ls` (bash, shell, powershell)  or `dir` (cmd).

- If your file (`App.js`) is listed on the output of the above command, then check the spelling and make sure the case exactly matches what you provided to `node`. That is   you command must be `node App` or `node App.js` and not `node app.js` or `node aPP.js`...
- If your file isn't listed (what is the more probable outcome) then go to `step 2`.

---

2. Get the full path of the folder containing your file (`App.js`) from your file explorer.

- On windows, just open the folder containing your file and copy the content of the address bar.
- On Linux, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file).
- On Mac, refer to this [other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317992/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-path-of-a-folder-in-macos)

---

3. In your terminal navigate to the above folder with the command 
   `cd copied_path`.

---

4. Check again the content of the path to make sure your command line is opened in the right folder.

---

5. Run `node App.js`

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is caused by the node_modules directory. In my case, I tried npm install with an old version of node(nodev12) for an app using nodev18. After I deleted nodev12, I also removed the node_modelues directory and ran npm install and it worked.