# How can I print the absolute paths of all files in the directory using a for loop?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, path

I want to find the absolute paths of every file in my current directory

Now, when I tried to just print out all the files inside the directory using

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in *; do
        echo $x
done
```

I get:

```
cd
file1
file1.txt
file2.txt
path
readfile
testfile
```

which is right, however, when I adapt this to get the paths instead by changing my existing code to

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in *; do
        echo $PATH
done
```

I get

```
    Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk11.0.16_9/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk17.0.4_9/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/:/snap/bin
    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk11.0.16_9/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk17.0.4_9/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindoFiles/Amazon Corretto/jdk11.0.16_9/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk17.0.4_9/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/:/snap/bin
   Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk11.0.16_9/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk17.0.4_9/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/:/snap/bin
    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk11.0.16_9/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk17.0.4_9/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindoFiles/Amazon Corretto/jdk11.0.16_9/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk17.0.4_9/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/:/snap/bin
```

repeatedly 7 times (which is the number of files that exists in the directory). However, this doesn't look like an absolute path at all since the file name isn't even mentioned in the paths of the output.

What should I change to make this work?

Comment: `$PATH` is unrelated to this, it doesn't mean the path of `$x`. Are you only looking for the full path of **regular files** in the current directory or **all** files (even directories/symlinks/sockets) and do you mean directly **in** the current directory or recursively (eg: include files in subdirs)

Comment: @Raxi path of regular files, not ALL, and i mean IN the current directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to get full path of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file)

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in *; do
        readlink -f "$x"
done
```

Comment: this is right but the paths are being printed seven times though, is there anyway for me to print it just once while using a for loop?

Comment: @Droid What would be your expected output then?