# Update all git repos in a folder in windows

Tags: windows, git, command-line

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15694215/1247080) answer is for linux command line. I need the same for Windows command line. I created the following using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055390/1247080), but my code does not work.

```
for /D /r %i in (*.*) do (cd %i && echo %i && git pull && cd ..)
```

#### Update

From @SevenEleven's answer and @kostix's comment the following worked.

```
for /D %%i in (.\*) do (cd "%%i" && git pull && cd..)
```

or

```
for /D %%i in (*) do (cd "%%i" & git pull && cd..)
```

Comment: If anyone has a version which checks whether we're on the default branch (e.g. `master` or `develop`) before doing the pull, and halts if not, that would be really cool!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
for /D %%i in (.\*) do (cd %%i && echo %%i && git pull && cd ..)
```

This script searches the subdirectories of the current directory (`for /D %%i in (.\*)`). It changes to every directory found (`cd %%i`), writes its name to console (`echo %%i`) and executes `git pull`

`/r` does search all subdirectories too. Since you don't want to search your projects subdirectories, that is not needed. If you search an absolute path, you can get rid of the `cd ..`:

Comment: @stat-r, one thing to note is that `%%` is for batcn files; if you will want to first test this in plain `cmd.exe`, use a single `%`. Another thing is that I would surround each `%%i` with double quotes -- to catch a possible case of a directory name containing spaces in it.

Comment: @Stat-R Yes, that's right. That's because of the relative path. If you search in an absolute path, this example should work without `cd ..`