# Snippet to update all repos in folder, respecting `main` vs `master`

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have an old shell snippet that I use (or to its alias) often that updates all the repos in a folder.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '(cd {} && git checkout master && git pull)' ';'
```

However, today many repos are converting to use `main` rather than `master`. In particular, GitHub now defaults to that. But there are still many repos that still use `master`.

I'm seeking a generic linux/macOS not-only-on-github replacement snippet (that I can alias) to checkout the correct branch (I'm willing to presume there is not both types) and pull.

That being said, if someone has a version of this that works with GitHub's `gh` tool, that would be useful. But I do need one that works outside of GitHub.

Another optional feature that I'd love is if the script can do the right thing if the `max-depth 1` repo explicitly has submodules.

Related other Stack Overflow questions:

- [Updating all repos in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694179/updating-all-repos-in-a-folder)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28666357/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+get+default+branch

Comment: As someone who advocates contributors rarely, if ever, checkout shared branches such as `master` or `main`, I find this question asking how to automate it, slightly amusing. ;) (Of course, I realize there are still plenty of use cases for checking out shared branches.)

Answer (score 1):

The gh version would involve getting the [default branch through API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084284/6309).

```
gh api /repos/{owner}/{repo} --jq '.default_branch'
```

That way, your remote repository could use master or main or any other branch as default, you would switch to the right one locally

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c \ 
  '(cd {} && \
    ownerRepo=$(git remote get-url origin) && \
    ownerRepo=${ownerRepo#https://github.com/} && \
    remoteBranch=$(gh api /repos/${ownerRepo} --jq '.default_branch') && \
    git switch ${remoteBranch} && git pull)' ';'
```

If you do not want to depend on a remote GitHub API, you can at least read [the *local* repository default branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28669194/6309):

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c \ 
  '(cd {} && \
    defaultBranch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD) && \
    defaultBranch=${defaultBranch#origin/} && \
    git switch ${defaultBranch} && git pull)' ';'
```