# Merge submodule changes after git pull on parent repository

Tags: git, git-merge, git-submodules, git-pull

*How to fetch&merge main repository and do the same for all submodules using **single** command?*

I have a repository *A* which includes submodule *B*.
Submodule *B* is often updated and changes are not always up to date.

I can update and merge new changes by doing following

```
cd A/B    <-- enter submodule directory
git pull  <-- run pull to fetch and !!merge!! submodule changes
```

What I want to do is to run single command to pull&merge main repository and do the same with all submodules.

```
cd A                           <-- Now enter to parent directory
git pull --recurse-submodules  <-- Fetch&merge changes on main repository
                               <-- and pull changes on all submodules
```

What actually happens is:

1. Changes on repository *A* are fetched and merged => **OK**
2. Changes on submodule repository *B* are only fetched and not merged => **NOK**

Current solution is:

```
cd A
git pull --recurse-submodules
cd B
git merge   <-- Now merge fetched changes from submodule remote
```

or:

```
cd A
git pull --recurse-submodules
git submodule foreach git merge origin master
```

Other questions I checked, without luck:

[Easy way to pull latest of all git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-to-pull-latest-of-all-git-submodules)

[Run git pull over all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497123/run-git-pull-over-all-subdirectories?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Running `git --help pull` on git version `2.20.1` I see this message:

> BUGS Using --recurse-submodules can only fetch new commits in already checked out submodules right now. When e.g. upstream added a new submodule in the just fetched commits of the superproject the submodule itself can not be fetched, making it impossible to check out that submodule later without having to do a fetch again. This is expected to be fixed in a future Git version.

*Is this related to the issue?*