# Submodule merge failure - "not checked out" warning

Tags: git

How can I merge this submodule after having had the following warning?

```
warning: Failed to merge submodule sites/all/modules/contrib/panelizer 
                (not checked out)
```

Comment: ...is the submodule checked out? (Did you ever run `git submodule update`?) Submodules are Git repositories within the main repository; they must be cloned into it and updated when necessary - `git submodule update` is the command which does this. If there aren't files in that directory, it's not checked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message comes from [`submodule.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/submodule.c), specifically the [`merge_submodule()` method](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/submodule.c#L787):

```
int merge_submodule(unsigned char result[20], const char *path,
                    const unsigned char base[20], const unsigned char a[20],
                    const unsigned char b[20], int search)
{
  struct commit *commit_base, *commit_a, *commit_b;
  int parent_count;
  struct object_array merges;

  // [...]

  if (add_submodule_odb(path)) {
    MERGE_WARNING(path, "not checked out");
    return 0;
  }
```

And the [`add_submodule_odb()` method](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/submodule.c#L25) is checking for `.git` presence within said submodule.

So, as Jefromi comments, you probably didn't do a `git submodule update` as described in the [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html).
You should see the SO question "**[Git - easy way pull latest of all submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/git-easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules)**" for more on how to get back the content of *all* your submodules.

With a recent git, you can [pull and update in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084186/6309):

```
git alias update_submodules='git pull --recurse-submodules && git submodule update'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response VonC; and thank you very much for that alias gem. I will switch to using that.