# how can i publish with push to git server with subprojects

Tags: git, openshift, subrepos

[image: screenshot]

I uploaded a yii website through git by pushing to ssh openShift server.
i had downloaded plugs with composer.
now all the plugs are being considered as subprojects, that means source code of these plugs ain't uploaded.
how can i stop the subproject feature

Comment: http://www.arlocarreon.com/blog/git/git-repo-inside-a-git-repo/
If you don't want a submodule, delete the git file in the submodule?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17571344/6194839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the submodules, see [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule/16162000#16162000)

After that, you can add stuff to your [`.gitignore` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), so that you don't accidentally add the files back:

```
file.php
dir/
```