# How do I manage a dotfiles repo when some directories contain git repos?

Tags: git

I apparently have some git repos in my `.vim` directory (generated by `Vundle` for each plugin) which I don't seem to be able to add/commit. In `bitbucket`, several folders don't get commited and some just appear as grayed out gitlinks.

When I try to `git pull` on another machine I just end up with the respective folders (where the submodules are) empty. I've had a look at this SO question

[Easy way pull latest of all submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules)

None of those were much help, and I think they relate to a slightly different situation (even if `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` worked, I was hoping for a solution a little easier to remember!).

I am not interested in setting up submodules unless this process can be automated (I don't want to set up a submodule everytime I add a plugin to vim), and I would really like to be able to keep my `.vim/` directory in my dotfiles repo without having to manually remove the `.git/` subdirectories from them (that would sort of defeat the purpose of dofiles repos, because it would make things harder rather than simplifying them!).

I want to stage, commit and push *everything* that I ask git to stage and commit, including all `.git/` directories and git-related files, without auto-generating any kind of submodules or gitlinks.

Can I do this? If so, how?

Comment: Don't put repositories inside repositories and you should be all good.

Comment: @knittl [Thanks dude](http://cdn.meme.li/instances/500x/54289792.jpg)

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. Delete all nested .git folders, remove the `.gitmodules` file, re-add (might require a `rm --cached`) all directories and files you need and commit?