# Stash everything in Git including all submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

When a project contains submodules you need to stash/unstash all of them separately. Is there a way to do it using less actions?

This link maybe helpful:

[Easy way pull latest of all submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules)

It is about "pull" command but there are some ways how to iterate between all the submodules.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `foreach` to run a specific git command on each sub-module. For example to apply 'git stash' to every modules use this:

```
git submodule foreach 'git stash'
```

Similarly, the following command will checkout `master` branch and then pull any updates from the remote source for each submodule.

```
git submodule foreach 'git checkout master; git pull'
```

Read more at: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Could you additionally explain: `git submodule foreach "(git checkout master; git pull)&"`? This command is used for pull for each submodule. Why do they add ampersand at the end and you don't do the same thing?

Comment: Also `&` at the end of a shell command will force shell to execute command in background. In this case you won't see output text from `git checkout master; git pull` command

Answer (score 3):

Warning: before Git .24 (Q4 2019), using "`git submodule foreach git stash`" could **lost local changes to submodules**.

See [commit 556895d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/556895d0c8e95a8c2fb41434a5b9bf453e9367f6) (12 Oct 2019) by [Jakob Jarmar (`jarmar`)](https://github.com/jarmar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bb52def](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb52def6dafabbfa07ee51562c9291222df55bd9), 18 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### [`stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/556895d0c8e95a8c2fb41434a5b9bf453e9367f6): avoid recursive hard reset on submodules
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jakob Jarmar</sup>
>
> [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) push does not recursively stash submodules, but if submodule.recurse is set, it may recursively **`reset --hard`** them.
>
> Having only the destructive action recurse is likely to be surprising behaviour, and unlikely to be desirable, so the easiest fix should be to ensure that the call to [`git reset --hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) never recurses into submodules.
>
> This matches the behavior of `check_changes_tracked_files,` which ignores submodules.

Answer (score 1):

I used to do what the answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558330/6149078) said, but it is not ideal really.

The reason it is not ideal is that if you don't have local changes in one of the submodules then `git stash` does nothing on that submodule, and when you do `git stash pop` you may have different stash queues that don't line up on multiple submodules.

There are workarounds, but I take a different approach:

What I have started doing, which is also not ideal (but might be more ideal) is:

```
git diff --submodule=diff > temp.patch
git apply -R temp.patch
```

And then to get back to my old state, I just go:

```
git apply temp.patch
```

And I also have `*.patch` in my list of files for git to ignore.