# Will git stash reset submodules?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-stash

I'm new to git. I wanted to stash my changes and do a `git pull origin master` on my branch. The project that I'm working on has submodules.

Those are the commands I ran :

1. `git status` - I can see all of my changes ( submodules + the main project )
2. `git stash push` no errors or warnings. I ran this in the main directory of my project
3. `git status` - All of the changes are gone ( submodules include )
4. `git pull origin master` - works ( updates the submodules as well due to some configuration in our environment )
5. `git stash pop` - no errors or warnings
6. `git status` - all the work done in the submodules is gone.

What happened ? I know that git stash is going to make commits for my stashed work and after that do a git `git reset --hard`. Why is my submodule work gone ? How do you  correctly stash a project with submodules ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Will git stash reset submodules?

No, `git stash push` does not save the changes within submodules (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29557635/10171966) and [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) that does not mention submodules at all) and it therefore does not revert those changes.