# pull from different repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am facing a strange situation. the problem started since our solution passed 2gb and bitbucket stop us from pushing into the repo.

i tried to clean up the solution and remove the history, but fact is our solution depends on many binary files and can't be shrunken so much, so i followed bitbucket solution and separated the image folder into another repositories.
before i break it into the different solution directory structure was like this:

```
solution
      | 
      \images
      |     |
      |     \tonline
      |     \donline
      \assets
```

the `images` without `tonline` is 1Gb, the `tonline` is 1.6gb, the `solution` is 600mb

so i created 3 different repository

1- solution
2- images
3- images\tonline

In live server I used to pull from just `solution`. so all the time i go there and simply type `git pull origin` and i bring the latest code from master.

but now the `images` folder is in another repository. and `tonline` is another repository that need to be placed inside `images`.

somehow i tried to encounter this so i create directory structure of `tonline` and `image` from root of solution. so if i clone `tonline` or `image` repository and copy it inside the solution, then it will be fine.

but it's a hassle, to clone separately and then copy them into one folder to form one solution again.

so i tried "pull from multi repository solutions". but i had no luck with it. i add different remote and pull one by one. i did it from root of the `solution`. so i expected after the `git pull` the merge result of `image` and `tonline` appear in the root of `solution` but it didn't

now my question is how can i have one line command to pull from both of these repositories?
I want to use git for live server as i used to do. so with minimum amount of down time i can update my code to latest version, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should look into git submodules which may help to structure your repo dependencies as needed, maybe [Easy way pull latest of all submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules) is good for a start