# pul git code to get new submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm using git with bitbucket.
I added some new submodules to git on my server with this command:
git submodule add --name   
This did the job, then I pushed it to the bitbucket and it all looks good.
But when I try to pull the changes from another server things are going wrong.
from the other server I run:
git pull and git submodule update, I get the changes in .gitmodule and it creates the folders of the submodule in the right place but they are empty!!!.
I can't go in to every empty submodule and run pull from the folder because I don't always know what submodule are added(sometimes other developers add them.)
I tried to add git submodule init before I run git submodule update but this didn't help.

Comment: Is this not already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules?rq=1 ?

Comment: no, I'm not talking about latest version of submodules but pulling new submodules that where not part of the code before.

Answer (score 1):

`git pull --recurse-submodules  && git submodule update --recursive`

Read the [Git Tools Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), for al the details.

Comment: would this also update the submodule to there last version? because this is something I would need to avoid.

Comment: Probably better to use `git fetch --recurse-submodules` as a _pull_ represents _fetch_ and _merge_ combined.

Comment: I'm looking at git fetch --help and it says:

BUGS
       Using --recurse-submodules can only fetch new commits in already checked out submodules right now. When e.g.
       upstream added a new submodule in the just fetched commits of the superproject the submodule itself can not be
       fetched, making it impossible to check out that submodule later without having to do a fetch again. This is
       expected to be fixed in a future Git version.

if I understand this correctly this is exactly my problem so it would not help :(