# Boost on Github locked the folders

Tags: git, boost, github

I used git clone to download `boost` project:

```
git clone https://github.com/boostorg/boost
```

when I opened some folder they where empty while I did not expect them.

I went to its folders through browser:

https://github.com/boostorg/boost/tree/master/libs

Why do I see most of folders locked here? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not locked. They are [submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

If you want to automatically download a repository with submodules as well, run this command

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost
```

If you have already downloaded the repo without the submodules, run

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

**Note:** these commands will pull in all the submodules. 
More on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules)

Comment: @ar2015: [`.gitmodules`](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/blob/master/.gitmodules) tells you where are these. In Boosts case, they live in the [BoostOrg](https://github.com/boostorg) account.

Comment: @ashman: That's because submodules don't live in that repo, but are repositories themselves. The correct link is https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem