# Distributed tensorflow fails with "BUILD file not found on package"

Tags: tensorflow

When attempting to build in the core/distributed_runtime module using:

```
$ bazel build -c opt 
   //tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc:grpc_tensorflow_server
```

We get the following error:

```
ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc': 
Extension file not found. Unable to load package for
   '//google/protobuf:protobuf.bzl': BUILD file not found on package path.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.097s
```

Are there additional steps required (and not mentioned in the README.md) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a git submodule issue—and it would affect building *any* part of TensorFlow from source. To recover, run the following command in your git repository:

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

(There are many other ways to do the same thing: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules) for some suggestions.)