# Understanding git submodule pulling and pushing

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have read the following articles:

1. [Git Tools - Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)
2. [git-submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)
3. [Git Submodules: Adding, Using, Removing, Updating](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/)
4. [easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27431025/2039740)

But I still do not 100% understand submodule handling. My questions are:

1. What does `git submodule update` do? Is it the same as doing `git submodule foreach git pull`?
2. What is the difference to `git submodule update --force`?
3. What is the difference to `git submodule sync`? And when do I have to call update and when do I have to call sync?
4. This question is a bit longer. I had to trigger a `git submodule update --init —recursive`. But why did no `git submodule update --force` or `git submodule sync` help? Please regard the following history of commands and outputs. I am sorry for the terrible formating. But I am somehow not able to insert this as code.

   ```
           - cd $gitproject
           - cd submodule_a
           - git status
               - ad96e1a11:og-appconfig-android knoppik$ git status
               - On branch develop
               - Your branch and 'origin/develop' have diverged,
               - and have 1 and 5 different commits each, respectively.
               -   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
               - nothing to commit, working directory clean
           - cd ..
           - git pull
           - git submodule update --force
           - git submodule sync
           - cd submodule_a
           - git status
               - ad96e1a11:og-appconfig-android knoppik$ git status
               - On branch develop
               - Your branch and 'origin/develop' have diverged,
               - and have 1 and 5 different commits each, respectively.
               -   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
               - nothing to commit, working directory clean
           - cd ..
           - rm -rf submodule_*
           - git submodule update --init --recursive
               - Submodule path ’submodule_a’: checked out '8d4d756f2342bc373b6e86f0d0246f7b502ba796‘
           - git status
               - On branch develop
               - Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
               - nothing to commit, working directory clean
           - cd submodule_a
           - git status
               - HEAD detached at 8d4d756
               - nothing to commit, working directory clean
   ```

So why did `git submodule update --force` not work? Why did I have to delete the submodule folders and run an init once again?