# git CLI how do I perform a checkout that also updates all of the submodules?

Tags: windows, git, git-submodules

So I can clone a branch and get all the submodules with:

```
git clone <url> -b myBranch --recursive
```

This is great :) But then I want to switch to a different branch, so I do:

```
git checkout myBranch2
```

This updated the top-level of my project, but not the submodules (I did not see a recursive option here). Infact I got an output that suggests it knows that the submodules need updating, but I just don't know how to do that part:

```
c:\dev> git checkout myBranch2
M        SubModule1
M        SubModule2
Branch myBranch2 set up to track remote branch myBranch2 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'myBranch2'
```

So then I checked the version of the SubModule1 and it is still pointing to the version that was originaly checked out (the latest) and not the version it should be pointing to (about 3 checkins older) that was associated with the branch myBranch2.

Of course I could just clone a new one and have both - this is what I would normally do, but it bugs me that I don't know how to do this... and it might be useful.

Comment: See if this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules

Comment: After `git checkout` do `git submodule update --checkout --recursive`

Comment: @zillani This question almost answers my question. I am not trying to pull any changes down as such, but I might have inferred how to do this from that question... thanks

Comment: @Leon perfect, this is exactly what I wanted. Tried it - worked. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `git checkout` run

```
git submodule update --checkout --recursive
```

From [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-update) documentation:

> **`git submodule update ...`**
>
> Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject
>   expects by cloning missing submodules and updating the working tree of
>   the submodules. The "updating" can be done in several ways depending
>   on command line options and the value of `submodule.<name>.update`
>   configuration variable. Supported update procedures are:
>
> - **checkout**  - the commit recorded in the superproject will be checked out in the submodule on a detached `HEAD`. This is done when
>     **`--checkout`** option is given, or no option is given, and
>     `submodule.<name>.update` is unset, or if it is set to `checkout`.
> - ...
>
> **`--recursive`**
>
> This option is only valid for `foreach`, `update`, `status` and `sync`
>   commands. Traverse submodules recursively. The operation is performed
>   not only in the submodules of the current repo, but also in any nested
>   submodules inside those submodules (and so on).

You can also set up a [`post-checkout` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) so that updating of submodules is performed automatically.

Comment: Thanks very much. The post-checkout hook idea is awesome, I would +1 you again if I could for that part. :)