# Add "git subtree" when the folder already existing with some file

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git repo "A" in which repo "B" is added as subtree by team member. I have clone the repository. Now there is a update in repo "B" and I want to pull those changes to my repository "A". I am unable to add repo "B" as subtree in my local hence unable to pull the updates. I need help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way pull latest of all submodules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules)