# How to use git submodules

Tags: git, github, command-line, git-submodules

I have a ./gitmodules file which looks like this:

```
[submodule "external/mpifx/origin"]
           path = external/mpifx/origin
           url = https://github.com/dftbplus/mpifx.git
[submodule "external/scalapackfx/origin"]
           path = external/scalapackfx/origin
           url = https://github.com/dftbplus/scalapackfx.git
```

How can I pull all of this submodules from the command line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032653/1135424

Comment: If you are fine with GUIs, I recommend using something like git kraken which helps configure and pull all these sub modules for you.

Comment: Thanks @nbari, git submodule update --init --recursive, was what I was looking for!