# How to update git sub-module to latest

Tags: git, github, dockerfile

Here I tried to update git submodule by using

```
git submodule update
```

and my text file is like this

```
[submodule "code/board"]
       path = code/board
       url = https://git.company.com/timeline/board
       branch = docker-board
```

When I use

```
git submodule update
```

It's downloading but it's not the latest

So how can I update it in to latest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to pull latest of all git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-to-pull-latest-of-all-git-submodules)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+submodules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
git pull --recurse-submodules
git submodule update --remote --recursive
```