# Does git pull --recurse-submodule really pulls latest commit in submodule?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-submodules

This thread's  ([Easy way to pull latest of all git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-to-pull-latest-of-all-git-submodules))  answer states that when running:

```
$ git pull --recurse-submodules
```

will pull the latest commits in the submodules. But when trying it, it doesn't seem to work.

I have a demo repo with a demo submodule called "tinyXml" (It's not the real tinyXml, just a demo). Take a look at the following shell interaction:

```
PS D:\DemoProject> cd .\tinyXml
PS D:\DemoProject\tinyXml> git status 
HEAD detached at 9101c63
nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS D:\DemoProject\tinyXml> cd ..     
PS D:\DemoProject> git pull --recurse-submodules                  
Fetching submodule tinyXml
Already up to date.
PS D:\DemoProject> cd .\tinyXml\
PS D:\DemoProject\tinyXml> git status      
HEAD detached at 9101c63
nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS D:\DemoProject\tinyXml> cd ..
PS D:\DemoProject> git submodule update --remote      
Submodule path 'tinyXml': checked out 'e249788ed10afbdff043f758f46add75b81d522a'
```

So you see that `git submodule update --remote` works, but `git pull --recurse-submodules` didn't pull the latest commit in the submodule.

My git version - 2.32.0

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no.  That's because submodules *are not supposed to use the latest commit*.

The **intent** of a submodule is that the *superproject* repository specifies which commit is to be used in the submodule.  The superproject repository does not list a branch name to be used in the submodule; that's *not reliable*.  So instead, the superproject repository lists the *raw hash ID* to be used in the submodule, as this *is* reliable.

The submodules are therefore checked out as "detached HEAD"s.  This is by design.

Remember that each submodule is a *separate Git repository*.  It is not part of the superproject.  The superproject repository simply lists the URL for *cloning* the submodule, so that Git can run `git clone`, plus the path (so that the superproject knows *where to put* the submodule) and the correct hash ID (so that the superproject knows which commit to use as the detached HEAD).

#### What you want instead

Now, there *is* a way, from the superproject repository, to make a request *to* the superproject Git to do something different in the submodule.  That way is *not* to run `git pull`.  Instead, you want `git submodule update`, with *specific flags*.  The specific flags you want *include, but are not necessarily limited to,* `--remote`.

I said above that the superproject does not list a branch for each submodule.  That's only partly true.  The superproject *can* list a branch name for each submodule.  But remember this: a branch name is just a way to say "get some particular commit".  Which particular commit *is* that?  Well, that's the tricky part, because *each Git repository has its own branch names*.  Your superproject Git has its own branch names, and each submodule that you've cloned has *its* own branch names, and the repositories from which each repository is cloned have *their* own branch names, and so on.

This gets very confusing, because at this point there are an absolute minimum of *four* Git repositories involved here:

- You have your own clone of the superproject, as your repository **R**.
- Your **R** has an `origin` from which you get commits.
- Your **R** has some submodule **S**, which your Git creates by running `git clone`.
- Your **S** has an `origin` from which *it* gets commits.

When you clone some Git repository, you get *all of their commits and none of their branches*.  Your Git then creates *one* branch in your own local repository.  Your Git takes their *branch* names and *changes* them, transforming them into your own Git's *remote-tracking names:* their `main` or `master` becomes your `origin/main` or `origin/master`, for instance.

This is also true for each of your submodules.  When your superproject Git runs `git clone url path/to/submodule` to clone some *other* repository as the submodule living in *`path/to/submodule`*, that *submodule* Git repository that this `git clone` command copies ... well, this is just like any other `git clone`.  Git copies, from that URL, all of their commits and none of their branches.  So a *branch* name is actually not useful here.  The "branch name" that your superproject repository **R** is allowed, but not required, to store for submodule **S** is not *your* branch name at all—since that's not useful—but rather a branch name *in **S**'s `origin`*.

Your superproject Git will, in **R**, run, in effect:

```
(cd path/to/S; git fetch)
```

This will make your Git-that-controls-**S** use `git fetch` to obtain commits from **S**'s `origin`.  This will update **S**'s *remote-tracking names*, such as **S**'s `origin/main` and `origin/feature` and so on.

If **R** says that **S** should use "branch feature", this really means that your Git, operating in **R**, should run:

```
(cd path/to/S; git fetch)
```

followed by:

```
(cd path/to/S; git rev-parse origin/feature)
```

This `git rev-parse` running inside **S** will obtain the commit hash ID for `origin/feature` as found in **S**, which was just updated by the `git fetch` that your Git ran *in* **S**, to get the raw hash ID.

This is what the `--remote` in `git submodule update --remote` means: after running `git fetch` in the submodule, use the branch name stored in **R** to construct the remote-tracking name that will be found in **S** to obtain the commit hash ID for a commit to look for in **S**.

The *rest* of the `git submodule update` command determines what to *do* with this hash ID.  With `--checkout`, the operation to do with this hash ID is a `git checkout` of a detached HEAD using that hash ID.

Hence:

```
git submodule update --recurse --checkout --remote
```

will enter each submodule **S** of your repository **R** and run `git fetch` and `git rev-parse` and do a detached-HEAD checkout *in* **S** as appropriate **and** will recurse inside **S** to update any submodules that **S** has.

You might not want `--checkout` though.  What you *do* want depends, on too many factors to really go into here.  The one thing I will note is that, once the submodules are on the commits you want them to be on, you need to make new *superproject* commits to *record these hash IDs* in the superproject(s).  This, too, can be painful.

#### This is insanely complicated.  Why is Git so hard?

Yes, it is.  I can't answer the "why", other than to note that this is, fundamentally, a hard *problem*.

#### This isn't what I want to do.  Why can't Git do _____ instead?

Someone is probably working on that right now.  There are projects underway to improve submodules.  It's ... hard.

This is what there is today.  Don't use `git pull`; it is not up to the job.  Even `git submodule update` may not be up to *your* job, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by your log, some of your submodules are not on a branch, but in a detached state.

You should enter each submodule and checkout the right branch, the go back and issue again the `git pull --recurse-submodules` command.