# Updating git submodule inside a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, .git-folder

I have a submodule inside my repo for example `repo/submodule1`. Inside `submodule1`there is another submodule, example: `repo/submodule1/submodule2`. Do I have to checkout and commit changes in `submodule1` to get `submodule2`'s changes? I'm wanting changes from `submodule2` to reflect into my `repo` repository. I've tried `git submodule update --init --recursive` from my `/repo/` repository but that doesn't seem to reflect any changes.

I've also tried deleting and reinitializing my `submodule1` from within `/repo/` but it's not working either, but may have done it wrong. I'd prefer to get this all working from only changes within `repo` and not needing to checkout any of the other submodules if possible.

Comment: "*Do I have to checkout and commit changes in submodule1 to get submodule2's changes?*" Yes. `git submodule update --init --recursive` -> `git submodule update --recursive --remote` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032653/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+update+recursive