# is there a way to create a GitHub pull request which updates the version of a submodule to the latest commit on its main branch

Tags: git, github, github-actions

Same as this question [Pull latest changes for all git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/pull-latest-changes-for-all-git-submodules) but I am looking for a way to create a GitHub pull request which updates the version of that submodule to the latest commit on its main branch.
This is to be run on a regular schedule and also automatically add a set of GitHub users as reviewers on the pull request.
Is this possible? any suggestions would be great. Couldn't find a way to create a PR anywhere online. All answers point to pulling the changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [Dependabot](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/about-dependabot-version-updates) that creates pull requests to keep your dependencies secure and up-to-date. As example, for git submodules, just add a file like this:

<kbd>.github/dependabot.yml</kbd>

```
# This dependabot.yml file will updates git submodules
version: 2
updates:

  # Maintain dependencies git submodules
  - package-ecosystem: "gitsubmodule"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
```

More info also [here](https://github.blog/2020-06-01-keep-all-your-packages-up-to-date-with-dependabot/)