git submodule update - specific branch?
With git submodule update I don't see an option to specify branch. What happens is, it will fetch either all branches or one (if --single-branch is specified), which is default, but not the custom.
With very big repositories, it is problematic, because I have to fetch wrong branches and then it will checkout from another "reference", not much related with default branch, making it much longer to update submodule and also taking more space (as it will fetch unnecessary branch).
Even if I have .gitmodules with branch specified, it is ignored. For example
let say default branch is master and I have this in .gitmodules:
[submodule "my/path/to/sub"]
    path = my/path/to/sub
    url = git@github.com:org/sub.git
    branch = 16.0

I would expect when doing git submodule update --init --single-branch, to fetch 16.0 branch, but what it does, it will fetch master branch and will then checkout to commit that is referenced by superproject.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032653/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/18797720/7976758 git submodule update --remote Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+update+branch git submodule update without --remote checks out to commit that is referenced by superproject, this is how submodules work.

I know that, but thats not what I am asking. --remote will fetch latest code from submodule remote. Thats not what I need. I need to fetch code referenced by superproject, but on specified branch. With --remote, yes it will fetch correct branch, but it will point to latest commit, not superproject referenced commit.
Problem here is that I want to save space when it is fetched (where wrong branch is taking extra space)

"I need to fetch code referenced by superproject, but on specified branch." git submodules cannot do that. You can implement it yourself with git submodules foreach. Or if there is just one submodule cd into the submodule, checkout/switch to the branch, cd back to the superproject.

I see. Would be nice if it could fetch specified branch and then checkout to specified commit. I guess it is safeguarding in cases that commit would not be available in that branch.

I don't think it's a safeguard. I think it's simply that nobody's implemented such a strange feature — fetch the same commit but with a different branch. Submodules mostly ignore branches and fetch/checkout commits, and for a commit it doesn't matter on what branch it is.

Problem is, that it does not ignore main/default branch. When doing update I always end up with default branch and then checked out commit (so that branch is useless). Unless there is an option to just checkout commit without keeping any branches?

"…that branch is useless…" Under "that branch" you mean [submodule "my/path/to/sub"]branch? AFAIK that branch is only used with git submodule update --remote. "Unless there is an option to just checkout commit without keeping any branches?" No because Git cannot fetch a random commit by ID. A branch is required. Submodules use the default branch.

I see. --depth=1 looks like a good alternative as I don't really care about history on submodules from superprojects. Though might be a bit more cumbersome to update to new commit later.
